# Sed extract all matches on the same line

Tags: bash, regex, sed

I have the following line:

`randomtext<News:Image>111</News:Image>morerandomtext<News:Image>abc123</News:Image>sometext<News:Image>321abc</News:Image>`

I can't make sed to extract the values between the `<News:Image>` and `</News:Image>` tags.

I tried with `sed -rn 's/<News:Image>/<\/News:Image>/p' feed2.xml` and could not make it work.

I need sed to output:

`111`

`abc123`

`321abc`

Answer (score 3):

Your `sed` string changes `<News:Image>` into `</News:Image>`, which is not what you want.

If we assume that none of the texts contains `<` then the following is a simple, straightforward substitution:

```
sed -n 's/[^<]*<News:Image>\([^<]*\)<\/News:Image>[^<]*/\1\n/gp' feed2.xml
```

This finds any text before and after the tag you want, then replaces the found string with what comes between the opening and closing tags, with a new-line appended.

In the more general case, eg where there may be different tags on the same line, this is most easily done with two `sed` calls:

```
sed -e 's/<News:Image>/\n&/g' -e 's/<\/News:Image>/&\n/g' feed2.xml | \
    sed -n 's/[^<]*<News:Image>\(.*\)<\/News:Image>/\1/gp'
```

The first pass isolates the tags on separate lines, by adding new-lines before and after, then the second pass extracts what lies between the opening and closing tags.